# What are other methods to induce ego depletion besides using emotional videos and thought suppression?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, motivation, cognitive-modeling, ego-depletion, self-control

Muraven and Baumeister (2000) proposed that self-control is a limited resource akin to strength or a muscle, to deplete this limited resource leads to subsequent self-regulatory failure. Ego depletion, the temporary depletion of self-regulatory capacity by an initial act of self-control, has a significant effect in decreasing performance in self-control tasks (Hagger et.al, 2010).

I would like to know the methods to induce ego depletion, so far I only come across studies using emotional videos and thought suppression (Baumeister et.al., 2003) to achieve this cognitive process.

1. Baumeister, R. F. (2003). Ego depletion and self‐regulation failure: A resource model of self‐control. Alcoholism: Clinical and Experimental Research, 27(2), 281-284. 
   DOI: 10.1097/01.ALC.0000060879.61384.A4
2. Hagger, M. S., Wood, C., Stiff, C., & Chatzisarantis, N. L. (2010). Ego depletion and the strength model of self-control: a meta-analysis. Psychological bulletin, 136(4), 495. http://dx.doi.org/10.1037/a0019486
3. Muraven, M., & Baumeister, R. F. (2000). Self-regulation and depletion of limited resources: Does self-control resemble a muscle?. Psychological bulletin, 126(2), 247. http://dx.doi.org/10.1037/0033-2909.126.2.247

Comment: Note that Hagger et al (2010)'s meta-analysis has since been [discredited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ego_depletion#Reproducibility_controversy_and_conflicting_meta_analyses), and newer meta-analyses failed to find a strong effect of ego depletion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the supplemental materials ([Appendix A](http://supp.apa.org/psycarticles/supplemental/bul_136_4_495/BUL-Hagger20090180-RRR-F2.doc)) of the meta-analysis by Hagger et al. (2010), you can find a comprehensive **taxonomy of different methods that have been used to induce ego depletion**. As the table summarizes a great variety of different paradigms, I will only list a few examples of methods and papers here. The references can be found in [this document](http://supp.apa.org/psycarticles/supplemental/bul_136_4_495/BUL-Hagger20090180-RRR-F1.doc).

Hagger et al. sort the methods into 3 "task spheres" depending on whether they focus more on affective or cognitive processes:

1. **Affective**

   - **controlling emotions** - for example *reading book passage aloud in emotionally expressive fashion* (Gailliot, Schmeichel, & Maner, 2007, Study 1), *regulating negative affect when describing a situation* (Bruyneel et al., 2009, Studies 3 & 4)
   - **controlling impulses** - for example *crossing-out-letters task* (e.g., Baumeister et al., 1998, Study 4), *modified Stroop task performance* (e.g., Bray, Ginis, Hicks, & Woodgate, 2008), *Appetizing/unappetizing food taste perception task* (e.g., Baumeister et al., 1998, Study 1)
2. **Cognitive**

   - **controlling attention** - for example *focusing attention on subject and not displayed words while watching a video* (e.g., DeWall et al., 2008, Study 2), *arithmetic task with/without auditory interference* (e.g., Alberts, Martijn, Greb, Merckelbach, & de Vries, 2007, Study 2)
   - **cognitive performance** - for example *paced forward (low fatigue)/backward (high fatigue) counting task* (e.g., Wright et al., 2007), *easy/difficult labyrinths task* (e.g., Alberts et al., 2007)
   - **controlling thoughts** - for example *suppressing thoughts of death* (e.g., Gailliot, Baumeister et al., 2007, Study 8), *suppressing thoughts of previously-viewed emotive video* (Ostafin et al., 2008)
   - **choice and volition** - for example *making product choices* (Bruyneel, Dewitte, Vohs, & Warlop, 2006), *forced-choice essay task* (e.g., Baumeister et al., 1998, Study 2)
3. **Affective and cognitive**

   - **social processing** - for example, *high-maintenance social interaction tasks* (e.g., Finkel et al., 2006), *other-race/same-race social interaction task* (e.g., Richeson & Shelton, 2003)

**References**

Hagger, M. S., Wood, C., Stiff, C., & Chatzisarantis, N. L. D. (2010). Ego depletion and the strength model of self-control: A meta-analysis. Psychological Bulletin, 136, 495–525. doi:10.1037/a0019486