# How to integrate word prediction keyboard into P300-based BCI (brain computer interface) system?

Tags: hci, brain-computer-interface, p300

See this question in [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/71990/how-to-integrate-word-prediction-keyboard-into-p300-based-bci-brain-computer-in).
Farwell and Donchin (1988) described a P300 based BCI selecting letters by detecting P300 responding to the flashing letters. According to this system, only one target can be detected each time, thus only one flashing group. If we use word prediction keyboard in this system, once a letter is selected, the predicted words will appear on the screen. If next letter and the predicted words flash at the same time, the system is not able to tell which to select. What's the best way to integrate word prediction keyboard into this system? two ideas below:

1. to have the keyboard disappeared after a letter is selected, only leave predicted words appear on the screen. If nothing is selected in a limited time, remove the words and the keyboard comes back, subject continues to spell.
2. same idea as above, instead of removing  the keyboard, just to stop the keyboard from flashing when the predicted words are flashing after a letter is selected.

However, both might slow down the spelling process if subjects only need words with 3 or fewer letters. Any other ideas?

[image]

Fig. 1. An example from the Brain-Computer Interface Laboratory at East Tennessee State University 
[To spell the word "DOG", as rows and columns flash successively, the user has to count how many times the letter 'D' (the target) flashes. This results in a P300 response being generated each time the row or column containing the target flashes. The twelve-flash series is repeated a predetermined number of times. The responses for each row and column are averaged, and a classifier is applied to determine how closely each averaged response resembles the P300. The intersection of the row and column with the highest classification values is selected. In this case, the row and column containing the target letter 'D' would be selected, and a "D" would be presented as feedback to the user on the line below the presented word "DOG" at the top of the matrix.]

Farwell, L. A., & Donchin, E. (1988). Talking off the top of your head: toward a mental prosthesis utilizing event-related brain potentials. Electroencephalography and clinical Neurophysiology, 70(6), 510-523. doi:10.1016/0013-4694(88)90149-6

Comment: Thank you for the question. Please try to avoid creating redundant tags. For example, on this question you created both the tag brain-computer-interface _and_ bci, and on a [previous question](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/9056/29) you introduced both error-related-negativity and ern; you should avoid creating multiple tags that mean the same things, and try to use existing tags as much as possible. I've fixed them on both this and the previous question. Also, although this question is on-topic here, it might get better response at [UX.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).